# vb.net Datatable to multible Datatables using Datatable.Select()

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

i've a Datatable that has a Column called sID with the values form 1 to 14 so i want to put each row with each sID in a new Datatable.

```
e.g Datatable1 contains all rows with sID=1
    Datatable2 contains all rows with sID=2
    Datatable3 contains all rows with sID=3
```

Now i am not sure how to use the Datatable.Select() to fill each Datatable with its rows.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datatable.Select() method is to select row(s), to fill each Datatable you need to populate it like this:

```
Dim dt as DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("sID")
dt.Columns.Add("Column2")

Dim dr as Datarow
Dim i as integer

for i = 0 to 3
dr = dt.NewRow()
dr(0) = sID
dr(1) = "Column2Value"
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
next i
```

Or from a database like this:

```
Sub FillData()
    ' 1
    ' Open connection
    Using c As New SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.[Default].DataConnectionString)
        c.Open()
        ' 2
        ' Create new DataAdapter
        Using a As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmployeeIDs", c)
            ' 3
            ' Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
            Dim t As New DataTable()

                ' 4
                ' Render data onto the screen
                ' dataGridView1.DataSource = t; // <-- From your designer
            a.Fill(t)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```